# If $(f'^{-\frac{1}{2}})''$ =0, then f is a Möbius transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $(f'^{-\frac{1}{2}})''$ =0, then f is a Möbius transformation.

How we can prove this?

Comment: If $g''=0$ then $g(x) = ax+b$.  Using this with $g = (f')^{-1/2}$ gives $$f'(x) = (ax+b)^{-2}.$$

Then integrating and considering the cases $a=0$ and $a\neq 0$ separately gives the intended result.